# Calculate Aggregate values in Sub query select statement SQL

Tags: sql

I want to run this query but it gives me error.

Column 'Order.OrderId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the `GROUP BY` clause.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT vc.VehicleCategoryName,
  (SELECT COUNT(oc.OrderId) FROM [Order] oc WHERE oc.OrderId = o.OrderId AND c.OrderStatusId = 2) AS completedTrip,
  (SELECT COUNT(oc.OrderId) FROM [Order] oc WHERE oc.OrderId = o.OrderId AND oc.OrderStatusId = 3) AS CanceledTrip
FROM [Order] o
INNER JOIN VehicleCategory vc ON vc.VehicleCategoryId = o.VehicleCategoryId
WHERE CAST(o.OrderTime AS date) = '2017-03-13'
GROUP BY vc.VehicleCategoryName;
```

I want to form my data like this:

```
VehicleCategoryName|Completed Trips | Canceled Trips
  Bugdet                100             20
  Premier               50              10
  Rocket                20              20
```

Please help what is wrong I am doing with aggregate  ?

Comment: Please don't use Javascript/HTML snippet formatting unless it is Javascript or HTML or CSS

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? There is non-standard SQL in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to the correlated subqueries. You can use `COUNT` on a `CASE` instead.

Try this:

```
select vc.VehicleCategoryName,
    count(case when o.OrderStatusId = 2 then 1 end) as completedTrip,
    count(case when o.OrderStatusId = 3 then 1 end) as CanceledTrip
from [Order] o
inner join VehicleCategory vc on vc.VehicleCategoryId = o.VehicleCategoryId
where cast(o.OrderTime as date) = '2017-03-13'
group by vc.VehicleCategoryName
```

It uses the fact the above case statement will return 1 only on the matched condition and null otherwise and `count` function counts only non null values.

Comment: Thank you, but what if i have to fetch value from another table Like Fare table to calculate Earnings. total earnings against each category ?

Comment: @naveedahmed - You can join the table with this.

Comment: can you please edit your answer please my table is Fare which has foreign key OrderId

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
vc.VehicleCategoryName   ,
SUM(CASE WHEN o.OrderStatusId = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as completedTrip , 
SUM(CASE WHEN o.OrderStatusId = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  as CanceledTrip 

FROM [Order] o

inner join VehicleCategory vc
on vc.VehicleCategoryId = o.VehicleCategoryId
where cast(o.OrderTime as date) = '2017-03-13' 

group by vc.VehicleCategoryName
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,

```
SELECT vc.VehicleCategoryName,
  (SELECT COUNT(oc.OrderId) FROM [Order] oc WHERE oc.OrderId = o.OrderId AND c.OrderStatusId = 2) AS completedTrip,
  (SELECT COUNT(oc.OrderId) FROM [Order] oc WHERE oc.OrderId = o.OrderId AND oc.OrderStatusId = 3) AS CanceledTrip
FROM [Order] o
INNER JOIN VehicleCategory vc ON vc.VehicleCategoryId = o.VehicleCategoryId
WHERE CAST(o.OrderTime AS date) = '2017-03-13'
GROUP BY vc.VehicleCategoryName,o.OrderId
```